# Disabling GPS or WIFI in IOS

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I just wanted to know if there was a way to either stop using the GPS chip or stop using the XPS service provided within the framework of IOS?  I am creating a test app and would like to be able to give the user the ability to just use the GPS signal or to use the WIFI assisted model in getting their location.  I know that disabling the GPS updates is just the stopUpdatingLocation but that stops all of CLLocation and I would still like to be able to get a location but from either the assisted model (XPS) or just use the GPS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a boring answer - no, it's not possible. There is no way to specify or even check which "channel" a location comes in from in IOS.

In this regard, Android is way better.